# Spring MVC bean mapping to HTTP GET request parameters similar to @BeanParam

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

In Jersey there is `@BeanParam` annotation with which I can have request parameters mapped to  bean attributes.

In Spring I can find only `@RequestBody` which obviously works with request body and not request parameters.

Is there a way to have request parameters mapped to a bean using Spring?

Comment: For that there is @ModelAttribute. You might want to read the web section of the reference guide.

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work; all bean attributes were null.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply create a Pojo Java Bean with fields with names that match your request parameters.

Then use this class as an argument for your request handler method (without any additional annotations)

```
public class Example {
   private String x;
   private Integer y;

   //Constructor without parameter needed!
   public Example(){}

   //Getter + Setter
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("someUrl")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String someHandler (Example example) {
          System.out.println(example.getX());
          return "redirect:someOtherUrl";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to annotating the parameter with `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well not entirely. This will always construct a new instance of an object, whereas `@ModelAttribute` can reuse an existing object from the session. So it is not fully equivalent...

Comment: @M.Deinum With normal `@EnableWebMvc` config, the application registers two `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` instances. One that handles arguments with `@ModelAttribute` (higher priority) and one that doesn't (catch all case). They work exactly the same way. So if there is a model attribute with the same name as the method parameter (or whatever it is resolved to), then that object will be used. The added benefit of `@ModelAttribute` is to set the name to a completely different value. This is done so that you provide your custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` before the catch-all one.

Comment: It works now, thanks, apparently it requires a setter, it doesn't work with public attributes. I will accept your answer.