# Issue when mapping GET request parameters with DTO object in Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have created a Spring Boot with Spring REST application.

This is my controller code.

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public Response getResponse(SampleDTO dto) {
    Response response = new Response();

    response.setResponseMsg("Hello "+dto.getFirstName());

    return response;
  }
}
```

This is my SampleDTO

```
public class SampleDTO {

  @JsonProperty("firstname")
  private String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

and this is my Response object

```
public class Response {

  private String responseMsg;

  public String getResponseMsg() {
    return responseMsg;
  }

  public void setResponseMsg(String responseMsg) {
    this.responseMsg = responseMsg;
  }
}
```

When I try to access service this way

http://localhost:8080/sample/get?firstName=mvg

I am getting this expected output

{"responseMsg":"Hello mvg"}

When I try to access service this way

http://localhost:8080/sample/get?firstname=mvg

I am getting this output

{"responseMsg":"Hello null"}

My question is how do I map 'firstname' in request parameter with 'firstName' of DTO?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your `SampleController` in your method add this annotation @RequestBody on the `SampleDTO` param

Comment: I am getting this error Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.sample.dto.Response com.sample.controller.SampleController.getResponse(com.sample.dto.SampleDTO) When I am adding this @RequestBody

Comment: then you are not fixing the json properly from your client / jsp

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting  @JsonProperty("firstname") make sure you are imported the this statement "import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty ;". One thing more if you are sending more properties and your bean class does not have that you can set the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) on the top of the bean name.

You are also missing the @RequestBody annotation. You should take this as (@RequestBody SampleDTO dto)in getResponse method.

Comment: I am getting this error

Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.sample.dto.Response com.sample.controller.SampleController.getResponse(com.sample.dto.SampleDTO)

When I am adding this @RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a Pojo Java Bean with fields with names that match your request parameters.

Then use this class as an argument for your request handler method (without any additional annotations)

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20203654/446008)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to choose which approach do you need (or want to use) param or model. When you use something like this `http://localhost:8080/sample/get?firstName=mvg` , you are passing data as request parameters. So you need to use the @RequestParam annotation.

Sample using @RequestParam annotation (use is explained in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam))

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Response foo(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName) {
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setResponseMsg("Hello "+ firstName );
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I need to know how do I do this with DTO object?

Comment: Map it with @Modelattribute - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: The url is working for me. :(. Try it again, please.

Comment: How this part "@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet" solves my problem??  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: First you need to choose which approach do you need (or want to use) param or model. When you use something like this http://localhost:8080/sample/get?firstName=mvg , you are passing data as parameters. So you need to use the @RequestParam annotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114008/discussion-between-mvg-and-joseripla).