# Equivalent annotations to Jersey @Context, @FormParm and @BeanParam in Spring

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

Consider the following Spring MVC annotation:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="content", 
                method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

The equivalent in JAX-RS/Jersey is:

```java
@GET
@Path("content")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

I am looking for the equivalent Spring MVC annotation for the following JAX-RS/Jersey annotations:

- `@Context`
- `@FormParm`
- `@BeanParam`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `@FormParam`

In JAX-RS, [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) binds the value(s) of a form parameter contained within a request entity body to a resource method parameter.

There's no *direct equivalent* to [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) in Spring MVC. The *closest* you will find is [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

```java
@RequestParam("foo") String foo
```

And you also can get the parameter from the request:

```java
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
```

### `@BeanParam`

In JAX-RS, [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) can be used to inject custom JAX-RS *parameter aggregator* value object into a resource class field, property or resource method parameter.

I'm not aware of any annotation that gives you a similar feature but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20203654/1426227), you can create a class with field names that match your request parameters and add it as a method argument in your request handler method.

### `@Context`

In JAX-RS, [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) is used to [inject JAX-RS contextual information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227) into a class field, bean property or method parameter. So you won't find a *direct equivalent* to [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) in Spring MVC either.

However Spring MVC has a [predefined set of types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) that can *automagically* injected in method arguments.

And you also can use [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) to inject some request/response contextual information in your class fields:

```java
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;
```