# Aggregating PathParams and QueryParams into a single Bean

Tags: rest, spring-boot, url-parameters

I want to gather all params in my `@RestController` into a single bean for passing them downstream.

With Jersey I would define a `@BeanParam`, what seems not possible with Spring-Boot.

I tried defining a Parameterbean with accessors named like the `@PathVariable`, annotated the setters arguments with `@PathVariable` and the same for the constructor.

I found up to 5 years old examples on SO with `@ModelAttribute` I desperatly gave a try, with no success.

So is there something I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I just fat fingered my param!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200979/spring-mvc-bean-mapping-to-http-get-request-parameters-similar-to-beanparam/20203654#20203654) answer works like charm for `@PathVariable` And `QueryVariable`.
What one would have to do is just model an object with fields named after the params and use it without any annotations on the controller method.

But be aware that any param gets matched and therefore could be overridden.
Also `ControllerLinkBuilder` (`linkTo` and `methodOn`) do not take the Parameters into account.